# Sending files from winCE device to server via GPRS

Tags: file-upload, windows-ce, gprs

I need to send files (*.zip, *.jpg, *.xml etc) from Windows CE 5.0 device to a server via GPRS. 
What are the options of sending files across to server?

I have been successful in sending some data using AT commands of Hayes compatible modem

AT-Command Interpreter ready
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","AIRTELGPRS.COM"
OK
AT%ETCPIP
OK
AT%ETCPIP?
%ETCPIP:1,"117.98.182.100",,"202.56.250.5","202.56.230.5"

OK
AT%OPEN="TCP","59.182.32.235",8001
CONNECT

AT%IOMODE=1
OK
AT%IPSEND="11"
%IPSEND:1,15
OK

However there is no command for sending files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use webservice on the server side and call the web service from client application - I think that you can do http requests from any common programming language/framework that targets WinCE.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are way to low in the stack. The AT commands you quoted are commands sent directly to the modem/module via serial/usb. You're setting up the APN and it looks like some simple TCP packet transmission.

You need to build a ppp session (DUN - dial-up networking session) to get the IP connectivity that will allow you to send files via common internet protocols like HTTP/FTP etc.

Typically once you've setup the APN in the first cid of the context you dial it via 'AT*99***1#'. This will enable the modem as a PPP endpoint. Keep in mind this can vary between modems.